# beautifulsoup title from resultset object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been at this for a while, but can't seem to get the text value of an element of a resultset object using beautifulsoup.  Here is the method that is failing:

```
def __getNameOfProduct(self, product):
    #product is of type bs4.resultset...

    for value in product:
        print value.find_all("div",class_="proddisc").title.string
```

Its my own markup so I don't have a url (I am working through a tutorial), but here is the error I am getting

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ctd.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "ctd.py", line 60, in main
    p.getItemsInStock()
  File "ctd.py", line 26, in getItemsInStock
    return self.__returnItemDetailAsDictionary(itemDetail)
  File "ctd.py", line 32, in __returnItemDetailAsDictionary
    nameOfProduct = self.__getNameOfProduct(product)
  File "ctd.py", line 44, in __getNameOfProduct
    print value.find_all("div",class_="proddisc").title.string
  AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: would it be possible for you to share: 1. the url of the page, 2. the exact error message.

Comment: Sure. Just added.  Its my own markup so I don't have a url. I am working through a tutorial and wanted to try some more advanced parsing.

Comment: then please paste the markup you ran your code on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way you accessing attribute is only valid for single object not for many_objects as you getting with "find_all".

as i got your requirement, this will work:

```
html = urllib.urlopen("http://yoursite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
prodisc_div = soup.findAll('div', attrs={class:"prodisc"})
for each in prodisc_div:
  print each.get("title")
```